# How to retrieve user's email_id, when he shares our app on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{My AppId}',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
  });
```

```
        FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
    }, function(response){
       alert("response.authResponse");});
```

Here I want to get user's email after sharing on facebook but I am unable to retrieve it.

Comment: Of course you don’t get the user’s email, just because they share something. If you want anyone’s email address, you need to make them login to your app and grant it appropriate permission first.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access user's data once they login to your app via Facebook and have granted appropriate [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference). The share dialog does not require special permissions which is why you are able to use it even without integrating login. If you want other capabilities like obtaining a user's public profile, email, etc, you need to integrate [Login with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) and [ask for the permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#adding) that you require.